# Count Non Null values in column in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, count, null

I have a dataframe which contains null values:

```python
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(125, '2012-10-10', 'tv'),
     (20, '2012-10-10', 'phone'),
     (40, '2012-10-10', 'tv'),
     (None, '2012-10-10', 'tv')],
    ["Sales", "date", "product"]
)
```

I need to count the Non Null values in the "Sales" column.

I tried 3 methods.

The first one I got it right:

```python
df.where(F.col("sales").isNotNull()).groupBy('product')\
  .agg((F.count(F.col("Sales")).alias("sales_count"))).show()

# product   | sales_count
# phone     |  1
# tv        |  2
```

The second one, it's not correct:

```python
df.groupBy('product')\
  .agg((F.count(F.col("Sales").isNotNull()).alias("sales_count"))).show()

# product   | sales_count
# phone     |  1
# tv        |  3
```

The third one, I got the error:

```python
 df.groupBy('product')\
   .agg((F.col("Sales").isNotNull().count()).alias("sales_count")).show()
```

> TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable

What might cause errors in the second and third methods?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first attempt of yours is filtering out the rows with `null` in `Sales` column before you did the aggregation. Thus it is giving you the correct result.

But with the second code

```
df.groupBy('product') \
    .agg((F.count(F.col("Sales").isNotNull()).alias("sales_count"))).show()
```

You haven't `filtered` out and did `aggregation` on whole dataset. If you analyze closely `F.col("Sales").isNotNull()` would give you *boolean* columns i.e. `true` and `false`. So `F.count(F.col("Sales").isNotNull())` *is just counting the *boolean* values in the grouped dataset which is evident if you create a new column as below*.

```
df.withColumn("isNotNull", F.col("Sales").isNotNull()).show()
```

which would give you

```
+-----+----------+-------+---------+
|Sales|      date|product|isNotNull|
+-----+----------+-------+---------+
|  125|2012-10-10|     tv|     true|
|   20|2012-10-10|  phone|     true|
|   40|2012-10-10|     tv|     true|
| null|2012-10-10|     tv|    false|
+-----+----------+-------+---------+
```

So the counts are correct with your second attempt.

For your third attempt, `.count()` is an action which cannot be used in aggregation transformation. *Only functions returning `Column` dataType can be used in `.agg()` and they can be inbuilt functions, UDFs or your own functions.*

Answer (score 6):

There is an easier way:

```
>>> df.groupBy("product").agg({"Sales":"count"}).show()
+-------+------------+
|product|count(Sales)|
+-------+------------+
|  phone|           1|
|     tv|           2|
+-------+------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Count non-null values

- only for every *string and numeric* column:

  ```py
  df.summary("count").show()
  # +-------+-----+----+-------+
  # |summary|Sales|date|product|
  # +-------+-----+----+-------+
  # |  count|    3|   4|      4|
  # +-------+-----+----+-------+
  ```
- for every column of any type:

  ```py
  df.agg(*[F.count(c).alias(c) for c in df.columns]).show()
  # +-----+----+-------+
  # |Sales|date|product|
  # +-----+----+-------+
  # |    3|   4|      4|
  # +-----+----+-------+
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the countIf() function .Inside the function place your condition like:

df.select(count_if(col("Sales").isNotNull()).show()

supports from spark 3.x